# How to convert activerecord result into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a query that returns results in ActiveRecord successfully.

```
select
    trunc(b.transaction_date) as transaction_date,
    sum(a.transaction_amount) as transaction_amount
from
  payment_transaction a,
  payment_settlement b
where
    a.transaction_status = 'S'
    and b.settlement_type = 'D'
    and trunc(b.transaction_date) > sysdate - 30
    and a.payment_transaction_id = b.payment_transaction_id
group by
    trunc(b.transaction_date)
order by
    trunc(b.transaction_date)
```

The above query returns 9 results.

What I want is to convert the entire result obtained above into a hash such as:

```
{
"01/01/16" => 764.00, 
"02/01/16" => 1508.00, 
"03/01/16" => 2000.00 
..
..
..
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is a "comma-separated hash"? Do you mean a normal hash (like `foo = {}`) or a string which looks like the above?

Comment: Just a normal hash. Apologize for the confusion. I will update my question above so that it reflects what is needed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resultArray = yourQueryResult.map{|e| [e["transaction_date"], e["transaction_amount"]]}.

theHash = Hash[*resultArray.flatten]
```

Haven't tested :)

Comment: Getting following error message: `undefined local variable or method transaction_date`

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
Hash[ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)]
```

To explain: there is no need to instantiate AR instances here, so just run your SQL. Using [select_rows](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_rows) will give you an array of arrays, where each element of the outer array is one row from the SQL result. Each inner array has two elements: the date and the transaction amount.

Now it just happens you can pass an array of two-element arrays to `Hash[]`, and it will interpret the first part of each inner array as the hash key, and the second part as the hash value.

**EDIT:** I'm assuming you are setting `sql` with something like this:

```
sql = <<-EOQ
    select
        trunc(b.transaction_date) as transaction_date,
        sum(a.transaction_amount) as transaction_amount
    from
      payment_transaction a,
      payment_settlement b
    where
        a.transaction_status = 'S'
        and b.settlement_type = 'D'
        and trunc(b.transaction_date) > sysdate - 30
        and a.payment_transaction_id = b.payment_transaction_id
    group by
        trunc(b.transaction_date)
    order by
        trunc(b.transaction_date)
EOQ
```

So that it is a string containing the SQL you'd like to run.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response Paul. But I am firing up my sql against one of  my model `PaymentTransaction` like this: `@sales_volume_for_last_30_days = PaymentTransaction.find_by_sql("          select ....")`. I am not sure how can I use the above-mentioned function to convert the data coming in that instance variable ?

Comment: If all you want is a hash of dates to amounts, don't do `PaymentTransaction.find_by_sql`. You aren't going to use the AR instances anyway. Instead do `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows`.

Comment: Note that my answer assumes the SQL string you wrote above is in the `sql` variable.

Comment: Ok. So I tried what you suggested and I am getting this error message: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: payment_transaction`. It is trying to connect to SQLite DB but I need to connect to Oracle DB to successfully execute the query.  I found this piece of code in one of the model: `class PaymentRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :payments_reporting_oracle
end` Would this help in fixing the problem ?

Comment: I am successfully able to connect to Oracle DB and execute queries against it but why does the above function points to SQLite. How can I make it point to Oracle DB so that your provided solution can be implemented?

Comment: It sounds like `PaymentRecord` is configured to point to a different database than the rest of the app. So I would replace `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` with `PaymentRecord.connection`.

Comment: BTW, `Hash[array_of_arrays]` and `array_of_arrays.to_h` will give you the same result (assuming a recent version of Ruby of course).

Comment: under rails 4.2 (possibly above) `exec_query` gives a nicer API than `select_rows`, still not instantiating lots of objects. Perhaps not necessary for the original question, but might help googlers like me.