# Convert UTC into Date in Ruby Hash whilst iterating

Tags: ruby, oracle

I have a `RUBY HASH` which is the result of the following `oracle-database` query:

```
Request.where("customer_id = #{customer.id} AND request_method != 'OPTIONS' AND request_time BETWEEN ?  AND ?",  start_time, end_time).group(:request_time).count(:request_time)

RESULT => {2022-04-21 14:07:16 UTC=>22, 2022-04-25 14:07:16 UTC=>3}
```

Is there a way in which I could iterate over the hash and convert the `UTC Format` to `DATE format` whilst keeping the value thus only changing the keys?

So that it looks like this:

```
{2022-04-21=>22, 2022-04-25=>3}
```

### What I tried

---

```
dates_init_hash = {}
(start_time.to_date..end_time.to_date).each do |date|
  dates_init_hash[date] = 0
end

requests.each do |key,value|    
   date = Date.parse(key.to_date.iso8601)
   puts date    
   next if dates_init_hash[date].nil?   
   dates_init_hash[date] += 1 
end
```

### My Thought

If I can convert the UTC directly after the database query, it would save me from running it through the `dates_init_hash` method.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking how to return the count for the `request_time` using only the date component and ignoring the time component. In Oracle, you would use:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(request_time) AS request_day,
       COUNT(request_time) AS num_requests
FROM   table_name
WHERE  customer_id = ?
AND    request_method != 'OPTIONS'
AND    request_time BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(request_time)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855196/1509264) appears to give a similar Ruby solution by directly calling the SQL (rather than trying to dynamically build the query in Ruby).